# Connection between Yosef and Chanukah

Tags: chanuka, yosef

The Megaleh Amukos makes a connection between Yosef and Antiochus in regards to the gematria of the names that Yosef is one more then Antiochus. I was wondering if anyone could explain the connection between Yosef and galus of Yavan?

Comment: https://www.jewishusedbooks.com/product.asp?productid=7599 Also the same for your other question.

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/12379 https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/97354

Comment: The translated and eludicated Zera Shimshon from ArtScroll has a special derush completely dedicated to this concept. It explains (Zera Shimshon, vol. 4, Bereishis, Mikeitz - Vayechi, p. 3: Derush 1: The Illimunation Of Chanukah), and brings the Megaleh Amukos (Ofen 252) that לכן אנטיוכ"ס שהוא בגימטריא יוסף - the gematria of Antiochus is the same as Yosef. Furthermore, the words "King of Greece" (156) is also the same as Yosef (156).

Comment: The Zera Shimshon brings the Zohar in parshas Vayeishev (49a) and explains that the Egyptian exile was a result of the sin of Yosef and because of the continuing baseless hatred amongst the people, the guilt of the sin of selling Yosef was reawakaned. Why? Because that baseless hatred was from the same caliber as when the brothers sold Yosef.

Comment: Thus, the Greek king Antiochus, whose name has the numerical value of Yosef, attacked the Jewish people because their baseless hatred had reawakened the sin of the sale of Yosef, and Antiochus therefore forbade them to fulfill mitzvos that would atone for that sin.

This is also, says the Zera Shimshon, why the Jewish people were freed at a specific time-window. When was it? When there was unity again, when the Jewish people would feel that they were one again. That is when the victory over the Greeks was.

Answer (score 1):

I hear a podcast this past week explaining this exact point. The dreams that Pharaoh had were representing how to prepare for the future when there is no food in Egypt. Chanukah represents the same idea of looking ahead in the future, and how to keep Judaism alive. That was the spiritual war being fought.
Although I did not do it justice I recommend the podcast https://spoti.fi/3YPmrdP